# Determining a probability- textbook problem

Tags: probability

I am really stuck with this problem. Don't even know where to begin. Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

*A high school senior applies for admission to college A and college B. He estimates that the probability of being admitted to A is 0.7, that his application will be rejected at B with probability 0.5, and that the probability of at least one of his applications being rejected is 0.6. What is the probability that he will be admitted to at least one of the colleges?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Let $A$ be the event the Senior is admitted to College A, and B the event the Senior is admitted to College B. Then 
$$\Pr(A\cup B)=\Pr(A)+\Pr(B)-\Pr(A\cap B).$$
From the information you were given, you can find all the items on the right-hand side.

Comment: Thanks. I think the answer is 0.8. But is my reasoning correct? If he is rejected at B with probability of 0.5, then he is accepted with probability 0.5 and if the probability of at least one of his applications being rejected is 0.6 then the probability that both will be accepted is 0.4. Therefore 0.7+0.5-0.4=0.8

Comment: You are welcome. The reasoning and answer in your comment are correct.